# O que é um arquivo .lock?

Tags: arquivo, composer, packages, yarn

Estou usando git para versionar um projeto e reparei ao verificar por modificações, que alguns arquivos .json têm um arquivo com mesmo nome, porém com extensão e conteúdo diferentes.

Exemplo: **composer.lock**, **yarn.lock**.

1. O que são?
2. Para que servem?
3. Devo versionar ou colocar no .gitignore?

Comment: veja se é esse o caso: https://githubengineering.com/git-concurrency-in-github-desktop/

Comment: e mais essa: https://yarnpkg.com/docs/yarn-lock/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os arquivos `.lock` nesses dois casos são gerados automaticamente pelo gerenciador de pacotes (composer ou yarn) para garantir qual a versão exata seu código está utilizando.

Nos arquivos `.json` correspondentes, você geralmente tem uma *constraint* de versão, que quando você atualiza (usando o `composer update` por exemplo) irá baixar a versão mais recente daquela dependência e em seguida será gerado um arquivo `.lock` com as versões que ele baixou.

Caso exista um arquivo `.lock` e você execute o comando `composer install`, você irá receber a versão exata que está no seu `.lock` e não mais a versão mais recente.

Na ausência de um arquivo `.lock`, o comando `install` tem o mesmo comportamento do `update`.

Exemplo:

- Você baixou seu projeto no GitHub e executou `composer install`, **sem** um arquivo `.lock` e tem a dependência `batata/db: 5.1.*` como *constraint*
- No final do comando, o arquivo .lock **é gerado** e você encontra a seguinte versão: `batata/db: 5.1.4`
- Você continuou com seu trabalho e **enviou** para o GitHub seu arquivo `.lock` que está na sua maquina
- A pessoa que mantêm o `batata/db` corrigiu um bug e decidiu gerar um *patch* alterando a **versão para 5.1.5**
- Agora, caso você instale seu projeto em outra maquina, com esse arquivo `.lock`, a versão que você irá receber **é a 5.1.4**. A dependência só será atualizada ao rodar `composer update`.

> Devo versionar ou colocar no .gitignore?

Essa é uma dúvida bem comum. A vantagem de se versionar o arquivo `.lock` é que garante que aquela **versão exata**, já testada será baixada, por exemplo, no seu servidor de produção. Assim você permite *deploys* automatizados onde um *script* baixa o repositório remoto no seu GitHub por exemplo e execute os comandos de `install` para baixar as dependências.

Por outro lado, se você está desenvolvendo um *package* que será utilizado em outros projetos, fica difícil garantir que todos os contribuidores do projetos tenham a mesma versão de determinada dependência, o que pode gerar vários conflitos nesses arquivos `.lock`. Nesses casos manter um arquivo `.lock` não é muito interessante e ter somente o `.json` já é suficiente, confiando no [*SemVer*](http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/) das suas dependências.